# How to make EclipseLink not generate primary keys and let that to the Database

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, liquibase

I use Liquibase to create the DDL schema of the database(Derby). Also, I use JPA and EclipseLink and I want to make EclipseLink so that it does not insert any values for primary keys and I want them to be generated through the pure sql. Now, I`ve tried to remove the generation type strategy in the entities, but it is trying to insert null values for PKs to the tables, which are not allowed for PKs.

I`ll be glad if you help me.

Now I have this, but it gives me the exception below.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4736444799522006644L;

    @ Id
    @ JsonIgnore
    @ GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE Role (
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
role VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [...] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.

Comment: are going to generate ids with sequence or how ? (on DB level)

Comment: id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)

Comment: The mappings seem fine, but it seems you are modifying an entity's ID value which the error states is not allowed.  What exactly are you trying to do in your application when the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sequence for generating IDs (instead of this GENERATED BY DEFAULT START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) . Its' a better approach and after that you can use your sequence in JPA:

```
   ...
    @Entity
    public class Employee {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EMP_SEQ")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="EMP_SEQ", sequenceName="EMP_SEQ", allocationSize=100)
        private long id;
        ...
    }
```

You can use sequence in SQL `<sequence>.NEXTVAL` to get new ID value.

For more info - please check https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing

Unfortunately this method won't work if your DB does not support sequences.

Or for your Derby DB you can try this (if primary key is generated as identity)

```
@Entity
public class EntityWithIdentityId {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;
     ....
}
```